# Interchange the value of a column having enum data type in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table whose structure and some values are as attached images.
The field `sex` is enum type and the probable values are "m" or "f". I have inserted some values as "m" and "f". By mistake I have inserted male values as `f` and female values as `m`. Now how shall I update with the right values by mysql query?
[image]
[image]

I have tried with the following

```
UPDATE table_name SET sex='m' WHERE sex='f';
```

After doing that all male values have been updated to female but how can I change the previous female to male?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enum` type is "nice" enough to let you use the empty string as a value.  You can either use that or alter the table to add a third enum value and then change it back.

```
UPDATE table_name SET sex = '' WHERE sex = 'f';
UPDATE table_name SET sex = 'f' WHERE sex = 'm';
UPDATE table_name SET sex = 'm' WHERE sex = '';
```

Comment: Is it possible using single query??